# PHP Check if there is method chaining or rerturn the result

Tags: php, chaining, method-chaining

If have a `Translation` class where I want to make this possible:

`$result = Translation::translate('input');`

This sholud return the result with the default properties set in the class or

`$result = Transltion::translate('input')->from('DE')->to('ES');`

...which should return the result with newly set properties with method chainung.

Is there a smooth way to achieve this?

Here is my class:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Api;


use App\Api\Helper\HasHtml;


class Translation
{

    use HttpRequest,
        HasHtml,
        ManageTranslations;


    public string $from = 'DE';

    public string $to = 'EN';

    public string $text = '';

    protected array $body;


    public function __construct( string $text )
    {
        

        $this->body = [
            'target_lang'         => $this->to,
            'source_lang'         => $this->from,
            'text'                => $this->text,
        ];

    }


    public static function translate( string $text ) : self
    {
        // either return new static with defaults
        // or check if from or to is called ??
        return new static($text);
    }


    public function from( string $language = 'DE' ) : self
    {

        $this->from = $language;

        return $this;
    }


    public function to( string $language = 'EN' ) : self
    {

        $this->to = $language;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

This solution works very well `Translation::translate()->from('DE')->to('EN')->text('input')`:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Api;


use App\Api\Helper\HasHtml;


class Translation
{

    use HttpRequest,
        HasHtml,
        ManageTranslations;


    public string $from = 'DE';

    public string $to = 'EN';

    public string $text = '';

    protected array $body;


    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->body = [
            'target_lang' => $this->to,
            'source_lang' => $this->from,
            'text'        => $this->text,
        ];

    }


    public static function translate() : self
    {

        return new static;
    }


    public function text( string $input )
    {

        $this->text = $input;

        // perform API call or somthing and return the result
    }


    public function from( string $language = 'DE' ) : self
    {

        $this->from = $language;

        return $this;
    }


    public function to( string $language = 'EN' ) : self
    {

        $this->to = $language;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

But the wording of the chaining is bit confusing and dirty.

Comment: No, your class cannot check whether there’s any chaining following. Period. Whatever you return from your methods must work as is on its own merits. E.g. by implementing custom toString to stringify any current state. Also, don’t try to be too cutesy and make PHP literally English with extra punctuation, it’s simply not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get close to what you want if you change the order of the methods.

Suppose you have a `translateText($input)` method:

```
$translator = new Translator('GER', 'ENG');
$english    = $translator->translateText('Ich bin ein Beliner.');
```

Now using the same `translate()` you could change the previous settings with:

```
$dutch = $translator->translateTo('DUT')
                    ->translateText('Ich bin ein Beliner.');
```

or

```
$spanish = $translator->translateTo('SPA')
                      ->translateFrom('DUT')
                      ->translateText('De kat op het spek binden.');
```

All the methods use chaining, except for `translateText($input)`, so you use that method as the last one in the chain.

I'm not quite sure this is helpful?

I prefer [the 3 letter language codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) in this case, because they are used more often in this usage case, although the 2 letter code is used as well.

I would be somewhat careful with using `static` in PHP, although I'll admit I use it myself. See, for instance: [Static Methods/Variables are bad practice](https://r.je/static-methods-bad-practice) <sub>(opinions are not always welcome on Stack Overflow)</sub>